# Custom rails task not showing up/loading in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, task, jobs, ruby-on-rails-6

In `rails-myapp/lib/tasks` I have a custom task called `orders.rake`:

```
namespace :orders do
    desc "fetch orders" do
        task :fetch do
           # come code
        end
    end
end
```

My understanding, this task should be available in the list when running `rails -T`.

I'm seeing this:

`rails notes                              # fetch orders`

Not sure this why the word of `notes` is showing up.

I supposed to be able to run this task by:

`rails orders:fetch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try so:

```
namespace :orders do
  desc "fetch orders"
  task :fetch do
    # come code
  end
end
```

Then:

```
rake orders:fetch
```

`rake notes` *is a task that shows your TODO list*